# Retrieving POST data in Node.js with Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post

As a disclaimer: I read many questions on here about this topic and they all sounded similar, but none of them helped me solve my problem, so I decided to post my own question.

I'm making an application using ReactJS for the front-end and using node.js with express for the backend. I have the following form in my ReactJS application:

```
handleFormSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        entries : this.state.entry
    };

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/todos",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.log("Sorry, there has been an error. Could not send data." + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}></input>
            <button type="submit">Submit List</button>
        </form>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add</button>
    <ul>
    {this.state.entry.map((data, n) => 
            <li key={"this"+data} id={n}>{this.state.entry[n]}></li>
        )
    }
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

}

Sidenote: /todos is a file in the router folder of my application that I access via `http://localhost:8001/todos`. The create-react-app is running on port 3000. (Not sure if it's relevant for this question, therefore I'll keep it short. I followed this tutorial https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/ to connect my react front-end with my node/express back-end).

This is how I'm currently trying to retrieve the data in node (in my app.js file):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.get('/todos/:entries', function (req, res, next) {
    Todo.findById(req.params.entries, function(err, todo) {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        res.json(todo);
        console.log(todo);
    });
});
```

But this is where I', kinda confused. Obviously it doesn't work, or at least I'm not getting the console.log message as I thought I should. In addition, in my form, I specify the todos.js file as file, that is supposed to receive the data, but all answers that I saw used `app.post()`. Do they use it in their app.js/server.js file or in the routed file? If so, how does that work exactly? And how would I be able to use the data in my routed file? Why does the way I do it not work? (If you need more information in order to answer that question, please let me know)

EDIT:

In app.js:

```
var todos = require('./routes/todos');
app.use('/todos', todos);
```

In todos.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    //didn't know how to retrieve the data here
});
```

Comment: first read doc http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: I updated my code above. I actually had a look at the docs yesterday, but I couldn't find where my main problem (that I don't know where the data is supposed to be retrieved, since I assumed it should be the routed file which I specified in my ajax request) is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npm install axios` this package and refer here https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

In react app you can use this code

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post('/user', data)
.then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
```

And For your Node express App you can use

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

This code is for cross origin error to access from different port

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, 
  Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT, POST, PATCH, 
    DELETE, GET');
    return res.status(200).json({});
}
   next();
})
```

And then you can use your code

```
app.get('/todos/:entries', function (req, res, next) {
Todo.findById(req.params.entries, function(err, todo) {
    if(err) res.send(err);
    res.json(todo);
    console.log(todo);
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, just one more question: do I put the node.js file in my app.js file or in todos.js?

Comment: okay so I just implemented this into my code, however, I don't know how to tell if it actually works. Do you know how I could test that?

Comment: Except Todo.findById(req.params.entries, function(err, todo) {
this code all should go in app.js

Comment: I don't quite understand. I put the last function (starting from app.get('/todos:entries...) in todos.js but now it tells me that app is undefined. Did you mean that I simply put everything frpm Todo.findById() until console.log(todo); }); into todos.js? if so, how does node know what I'm referring to?

Comment: You can look my repo for reference I had created express app https://github.com/rajatdhoot123/express_server
till I will try to explain you from scratch

Comment: You can get the reference from Official Docs

I thought you havent define app like

var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/todos/:entries', function (req, res, next) {

})

Try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162799/discussion-between-rajat-dhoot-and-a-s-j).

Comment: sorry, for the delay, but I'm back now